# how to sum two columns from different tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, union-all

I need to sum the data from two different columns located in different tables and grouped by session_id.....

[image: FIRST TABLE]

[image: second table]

I need to sum the column of spent_points + price_points grouped by session_id

this is the result i hope to get

[image: this is the result i hope to get]

I have tried with this query but I have only managed to group the data but I have not been able to sum it by session_id

```
SELECT session_details.session_id,SUM(session_details.spent_points) AS total_sum_session FROM session_details WHERE session_details.session_id IN ("-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy") GROUP BY session_details.session_id UNION SELECT template_sales.session_id, SUM(template_sales.price_points) AS total_sum_sales FROM template_sales WHERE template_sales.session_id IN ("-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy") GROUP BY template_sales.session_id
```

Comment: Union, then sum over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `UNION ALL` to get all the rows from the 2 tables that you want and then aggregate:

```
SELECT session_id, SUM(points) AS total_points
FROM (
  SELECT session_id, spent_points AS points
  FROM session_details 
  WHERE session_id IN ("-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy") 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT session_id, price_points
  FROM template_sales 
  WHERE session_id IN ("-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy") 
) t
GROUP BY session_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
WITH union_rows (session_id, points) AS (
        SELECT session_details.session_id, session_details.spent_points
          FROM session_details
         WHERE session_details.session_id IN ('-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7','-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy')
         UNION ALL
        SELECT template_sales.session_id, template_sales.price_points
          FROM template_sales
         WHERE template_sales.session_id IN ('-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7','-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy')
     )
SELECT session_id
     , SUM(points) AS total_sum
  FROM union_rows
 GROUP BY session_id
;
```

If you have an older version of MySQL, without `WITH clause` support, use a derived table instead.

The session_id filter can be done outside the CTE term, but then you may carry all those other rows as well, until the filter is processed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do a JOIN between this two tables using the session_id.
After that you can sum the two attributes.

It'll be something like this:

```
SELECT session_details.session_id,SUM(SD.SPENT_POINTS + TSS.PRICE_POINTS ) AS total_sum_session 
FROM session_details SD
JOIN template_sales.session_id TSS ON SD.SESSION_ID = TSS.SESSION_ID
WHERE SD.session_id IN ("-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy") 
GROUP BY SD.session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.session_id,SUM(A.Total) AS Total
FROM 
(
  SELECT session_details.session_id,session_details.spent_points AS Total
  FROM session_details 
  WHERE session_details.session_id IN ("-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","- 
  Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy") 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT template_sales.session_id, template_sales.price_points AS Total
  FROM template_sales 
  WHERE template_sales.session_id 
  IN ("-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy") 
) AS A
GROUP BY A.session_id
```

Comment: You would need UNION ALL to avoid dropping rows if sessionId and points were the same in both tables.